# How to display milliseconds in Google Annotatedtimeline?

Tags: google-visualization

Can you please help me with the dateFormat specifier for Google Visualisation APIs so that I can display milliseconds.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To set the milliseconds of a Date instance in javascript, use the setMilliseconds() method:

```
x = new Date(2009, 7, 6, 20, 10, 10);
x.setMilliseconds(10);
```

I suspect that Google Annotated Timeline will show values in milliseconds, though.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to use something like 'new Date(2008, 1 ,1, 00, 00, 00, 15))' that Annotated timeline seems to accept (and build entries for). The scaling (spacing) between the different entries also (seems to) takes into account the milliseconds. If only Google allowed millisecond display.